A problem about fitting a vector on its error.
According to the Fourier series, we can fitting an function within a series of sin(s) and cos(s), and they are Pairwise orthogonal. Once the series is converge, we can conclude that the error between its limited function and partical sum is going to zero so that Sometimes we can ignore high frequency signal and approximate the function.
Now I want to turn to an example after discretization. Assume that there is a vector $x \in R^n$, and I want to approximate it within an normal orthogonal basis. I choose the basis from the Eigenvector of Matrix:
$$
L = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1&-1/2&0&0&\cdots&0\\
-1/2&1&-1/2&0&\cdots&0\\
0&-1/2&1&-1/2&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&-1/2&1
\end{matrix}
\right]_{n}
$$
and the eigenvalue is sorted from small to large in the diagonalization of L
I express x by the eigenvector of L, and I abandon some back items. To my surprise, the approximation is good but it vibrates on both side, which is similiar to Runge Phenomenon.
The choice of the Matrix is inspired by the discrete Laplace operator, and I meet two problems that I can't explain.

Why the approximation vibrates on both side?
Is there any association with the Matrix itself? I try some other symmetrical Matrix the error is huge when I abandon some items even in the interior.

I express the vector in parameter form so that I can draw it. The following is the MATLAB code I used to calculate and the image I draw to approximate a circle.
Any hints or ideas is helpful! Thanks in advance!
T=[0:0.01:2 * pi];
N = length(T);
x=cos(T) + randn(1, N) * 0.01;
y=sin(T) + randn(1, N) * 0.01;
plot(x, y, 'b');hold on;
L = zeros(N, N);
L(N, N) = 1;
for i = 1 : N
    for j = 1 : i
        if j == i - 1
            L(i, j) = -1/2;
            L(j, i) = L(i, j);
        elseif j == i
            L(i, j) = 3;
        end
    end
end

[V, D] = eig(L);

A = V * D * V';

a1 = V' * x';
a2 = V' * y';

for i = 50:N
    a1(i) = 0;
    a2(i) = 0;
end

x = V * a1;
y = V * a2;
plot(x, y, 'r');



What does "vibrate" mean here ? In what sense is this similar to the Runge-phenomenon (which means that determining the roots of a polynomial is numerically very unstable and that polynomials with high degrees can oscillate heavily) ?

@Peter Sorry for the late response. My "vibrate" here means that when I consider the error of the vector x and the linear representation, it changes fiercely on the dimension in the front and back and fits well in the center. It's similiar to Runge-phenomenon visually. I don't know whether it is a well-defined question because the phenomenon seems Unconscious.

@Peter In the question I do the same operation to both x and y(which are long vectors represent the coordinates), and if I only want to fit x, we can use 1,2,3,...,n as horizontal axis and the phenomenon of "vibrate" looks the same.
